# Moment.js/Bootstrap Datepicker not showing values upon load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, momentjs

This piece of code is expected to be working but it is not. The field upon load is empty even though the model property has value. It is nullable DateTime property:

```
$('#PublishDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MMM/DD/YYYY'
    });
```

Changing the value then submitting shows that the value was captured properly but remains empty upon loading the view.

Answer (score 0):

It won't load for some reason, I tried before, it has something to do with datetimepicker I assume.

what i did was, after init datetimepicker, i used jquery to load the initial value
in your case,

```
//init datetimepicker
$('#PublishDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MMM/DD/YYYY'
});
// Manually set the value 
$("#PublishDate").val('@Html.Raw(Model.PublishDate)');
```

There might be other way, I am just sharing my solution.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that approach.